Gcloud app deploy not including images during deployment
I have the following command
gcloud app deploy --verbosity=info app.yaml index.yaml
Inside my project are some static images which I changed.
static/img/jpeg2.jpg
They are not being reflected on the deployment.
app.yaml
url: /static/
static_dir: static
expiration: "365d"
How does gcloud app deploy know what files to push? Can I ask for assistance where else they can be stored to help me ensure state is updated? I cleared cache on my local browser.

gcloud app deploy only deploys files that have changed recently (default is 15 days; for a detailed explanation, see the "background" section of this blog article from us).
Even when your "new" image is deployed, if it has the same name as a previously deployed image, you might see the old image due to caching issues. Solution is to employ cache bursting techniques. See this SO answer

As a developer is there anything in our power to clear the cache?

Don't think you can clear it per se. There's caching from Google end (controlled by your expiration attribute in your app.yaml file. The lower it is, the faster Google will serve a 'fresh' content of your static file. There's caching by your user's browser. You don't control that and I think using a 'new' name is what will cause the browser to get fresh content (new is simply anything that makes the url of the changed file different from that of the old file and folks usually do this by adding query parameters)
